# Does coercivity/supercoercivity conjugates?

Tags: real-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, duality

According to Wikipedia, a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty, +\infty\}$ is called coercive if,

$$f(x) \to +\infty \text{ as }  \|x\| \to +\infty$$

and it is super-coercive if

$$\lim_{\|x\| \to \infty} f(x)/\|x\| \to +\infty$$

My question is, does the Fenchel dual $f^\star$ share the same property?

Can assume $f$ is convex, lower semicontinuous, etc. on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The conjugate of the constant zero is the indicator of zero (and vice versa). More generally, the conjugate of the indicator of a closed convex set is positively one-homgeneous (and hence, not super coercive).

Comment: Do you know if there are any condition when these properties conjugate?

Comment: It's more like "the smoother f, the more coercive is f*", somehow. What is true, is that an f with L-Lipschitz gradient has a conjugate that is L-strongly convex (and this, coercive). So, for example $x\mapsto \|x\|^2/2$ is its own conjugate and both smooth and coercive.